# access - update field based on another field of same record

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've a table with many fields, among the others are the fields `Operator` and `Cost`. I want that when a certain name is inserted in the field `Operator`, the field `Cost` of the same record is updated with a fixed value that I choose.

For example, when I create a new row and insert the name `John` in the field `Operator`, I want that the `Cost` field, automatically update itself with the value `12`.

The possible names are only 4 or 5

Comment: You can create a trigger for it.

Comment: @Learning How? I can't find anything about trigger in access 2013

Answer (score 0):

When you update through a form you can write some VBA code on the operator field after update event and in this method you can set the value of Cost

```
  Private Sub txtOperator_AfterUpdate()
  Cost = 12
  End Sub
```

Cost is a calculated field based on another field and it is considered bad practice to store this in a table. You don't need to, whatever method you use to calculate the field you can use at the time you want to output the results. Your best solution is likely to create a table of operators and costs and use a DLookup to find the cost based on the operator when you need to.